# Nodatime and days in month

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm trying to get the number of days in a month. So I have the following

```
var fromdate = LocalDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now).Date;
```

Now I just need the number of days in that LocalDateTime variable that I just created. It seems like I could enter:

```
var m =  fromdate.Calendar.GetDaysInMonth(year, month)
```

But I already know the year/month in `fromdate`. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "But I already know the year/month in fromdate" - yes, but that isn't part of the `CalendarSystem` returned by `fromdate.Calendar`. If you're always using the ISO calendar system, you can just use `CalendarSystem.Iso.GetDaysInMonth` instead of going via the `LocalDateTime`. Or indeed `DateTime.DaysInMonth` will give the same result - there's no real need to use Noda Time here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime's GetDaysInMonth method:

```
int days = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);
```